# Как вызвать массив из функции?

Tags: python, sqlite

```
def content_page(number_page):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite')
    c = conn.cursor()
    co = str(number_page)
    content = 'SELECT * FROM Сontent WHERE id = '+co+''
    c.execute(content)
    rows = c.fetchone()
    # закрываем соединение с базой
    c.close()
    conn.close()
    content_data = []
    content_data += rows
    return content_data

number_page = 1
content_page(number_page)
```

если так: `content_data = content_page()`

тогда получается ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...............
, line 30, in <module>
    content_data = content_page()
TypeError: content_page() missing 1 required positional argument: 'number_page'
```

Comment: Забыли передать аргумент - номер страницы. Вот так должно быть `content_data = content_page(number_page)`

Comment: да, но тогда мне нужно чтобы      `number_page = 1     content_page(number_page)`   был внизу... а не перед  
 `content_data = content_page(number_page)`

Comment: номер страницы должен быть после, иначе контент НЕ подгружается

Comment: А как вы собираетесь вызывать функцию без аргумента, когда у нее есть параметр (номер страницы)?)

Comment: в сторону: зачем вы sql запросы руками собираете, вместо использования параметризированных запросов таких как: `c.execute('SELECT * FROM Сontent WHERE id = ?', (number_page,))`? Вы уже несколько вопросов про sql задали, я уверен кто-то уже упомянул, что не следует руками значения внутри sql форматировать—это не безопасно, может быть менее эффективно и больше шансов ошибку совершить.